# Sticky List Header Using Cursor Adapter

Tags: android

need help!

How do implement a sticky list header in cursor adapter.

I want a list like this

> Header: December, 2014
>   
> child:  day1 3000Kyats
>   
> ...
>   
> child: day30 4000Kyats
>   
> Header: January 2015
>   
> child: day1 10000Kyats
>   
> .....
>   
> child: day30 4000Kyats
>   
> Header: Feburay 2015
>   
> child: day1 10000Kyats
>   
> .....
>   
> child: day28 4000Kyats

query

```
SELECT SUM(KeyAmount), DAY(KeyDate), MONTHNAME(MONTH(KeyDate)), YEAR(KeyDate)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY DAY(KeyDate), MONTH(KeyDate), YEAR(KeyDate)
ORDER BY YEAR(KeyDate), MONTH(KeyDate), DAY(KeyDate)
```

query result

```
Amount Day Month Year

20 29 December 2014
44 30 December 2014
25 1 January 2015
```

The objective is to show the sum of daily revenue with a header. Under one header, there will be a list of days of that month.
It's easy with base adapter but I'm afraid that it would be slow. How do I do it using cursor adapter? is there a way?

Thanks

Comment: have you find the solution for this

Comment: No, I have moved on to other project. Sorry.

Comment: do you have any idea how to implement this with cursoradapter

Answer (score 1):

If the cursor is ordered by alphabet, you need to use `cursor.moveToPisition(i);`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements StickListHeadersAdapter{
  public long getHeaderId(int i){
    mCursor.moveToPosition(i);
    int j = mCursor.getColumnIndex("Column_of_name");
    String name = mCursor.getString(j);
    return name.charAt(0);
  }

  public View getHeaderView(int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup){
    HeaderViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView != null){
      holder = (HeaderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    else{
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_header_tree, viewGroup, false);
      holder = new HeaderViewHolder(convertView);
      convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    mCursor.moveToPosition(i);
    int j = mCursor.getColumnIndex("Column_of_name");
    String name = mCursor.getString(j);
    String headerText = "" + name.charAt(0);
    holder.tvHeader.setText(headerText);
    return convertView;
  }

  //Using butterknife so HeaderViewHolder:
   static class HeaderViewHolder {
        @InjectView(R.id.tvHeader) TextView tvHeader;

        public HeaderViewHolder(View view) {
            ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using `RecyclerView`, use this [library](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) and override `getHeaderId(int position)` with your months data coming out from cursor adapter.

I think it would solve your needs.

Comment: I got it. thanks bro.
I thought that adapter in the sample extends StickyListHeadersAdapter.
Actually, it implements. Sorry my bad :D

Comment: Please post the code. There is no `overriding` of `getHeaderId()`. It is an `interface` so we are just `implementing` the methods. The cursor doesn't really have a position so how is the `getHeaderId` handled?